# Retrieve Completion Date for Jira

Tags: python, jira

I wanted to get the date when the JIRA was marked completed with my project. However, I am not sure what the parameter is

```
issues_in_proj = jira.search_issues('project=MRIPS')
```

Expected result looks like this

```
[<JIRA Issue: key='MRIPS-6651', id='561340'> <and date completed here>,
```

Answer (score 0):

check this it may be help you ([git project](https://github.com/wogscpar/SZZUnleashed/blob/master/fetch_jira_bugs/fetch.py))
 , you can see his result [here](https://github.com/wogscpar/SZZUnleashed/blob/master/examples/data/issues/res0.json) and his [description](https://github.com/wogscpar/SZZUnleashed/blob/master/examples/Fetch.md)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the resolution date system field in Jira. This is set when the resolution field is changed, usually when an issue is closed

Comment: do you know what the parameter would be to call it?